# Amour, délice et orgue

Tags: pluriel, genre

Les mots amour, délice et orgue sont généralement masculins au singulier et féminins au pluriel.

P. ex.

> Peu de femmes aiment parler de leurs amours clandestines.
>
> Sans aucun doute, ils filent le parfait amour.

Pourquoi ce changement en genre ? Est-ce pour des raisons littéraires ?
Y a-t-il un mouvement des grammairiens pour que de telles anomalies disparaissent du français ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En effet, les mots "amour", "délice" et "orgue" sont des exceptions de la langue française où le mot change de genre au pluriel. Attention cependant, le changement de genre ne s'applique pas nécessairement.

- Amour : devient féminin uniquement si le sens du mot est relatif à une relation amoureuse.
- Orgue : Ne devient féminin que si l'on parle de l'instrument de musique et qu'il n'est pas mélangé à d'autres. S'il l'est, il reste masculin.
- Délice : Change effectivement de genre.
- Aigle : Au pluriel, le mot passe au féminin si le sens du mot ne concerne pas l'animal.

Les raisons sont effectivement historiques.

Source :

- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluriels_irr%C3%A9guliers_en_fran%C3%A7ais
- http://ameliorersonfrancais.com/grammaire/genres/amour-delice-orgue/

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour après quelques recherches

> Le mystère plane quant à  savoir pourquoi orgue et délice changent de genre en même temps que de nombre. C’est toutefois grâce (ou à  cause, c’est selon le point de vue) aux poètes que le mot amour partage cette particularité.
>   Inépuisable source d’inspiration, le sentiment amoureux était personnifié par le dieu Amour sous la plume des poètes. À force de parler de la divinité masculine, le mot amour qui était alors féminin est passé dans le camp viril au singulier. Quant au pluriel, comme il est beaucoup moins utilisé, il a gardé le genre féminin.

Source: [ameliorersonfrancais](http://ameliorersonfrancais.com/grammaire/genres/amour-delice-orgue/)